# Bad button positioning

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="head-btn wow fadeInLeft">
  <a href="#intro" class="btn-primary">Get started</a>
  <a href="#intro" class="btn-default">Read more</a>
</div>

.head-btn {
margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.btn-default {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 30px 0 10px;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 80px;
}
```

But in small sizes its look like that:

[image]

Please helpm me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `<a></a>` element is `inline` element, and `inline` element will wrap by default if its contents **overflow**. Because the default `overflow` attribute is `visible`, so your `more` displays in the next line to `Read`.

To fix this, add a line `white-space:nowrap;` to force your `btn-default` element not to wrap when the contents **overflow**.

For more about inline element, please refer to https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#inline-boxes .

Comment: My solution was add this lines display: inline-block;
     white-space:nowrap;

Comment: ok. inline-block will helps you setting the height or possibly positions of the `a` element.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to add `display:block;` to the buttons?

Comment: Yes, it doesnt help

Comment: This is the right answer. Check you're applying `display:block` to the right element

Answer (score 0):

As a quick and dirty fix, try changing `Read more` to `Read&nbsp;more` -- the `&nbsp;` (non-breaking space) will prevent wrapping between words.